# Nested eager loading constraints

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Post::with('comments.owner')->get();

This query will get us all the posts, its comments and comment owner .

But how can I get all the posts , its **last 5 comments** and authors for each comments . Can any one help please ?

Here is the schema
Posts - id - content
Comments - id - commented_id (user_id) - user_id
User - id - full_name
Thanks

Comment: please post your DB schema

Comment: Posts - id - content
Comments - id - commented_id (user_id) - user_id
User - id - full_name

Comment: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments'=>function($query){
                $query->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(5);
            }])
            ->with('comments.author')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working as expected. Its returning all the comments. I just need last 5
 
Please see the  queries ran below

select * from `posts`

select * from `comments` where `comments `.`post_id` in ('6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26')

Comment: two select statements  ?

Comment: Yes eager loading will not use join. It generate multiple queries

Comment: How about take(5) ?

Comment: @jaysingkar In Laravel you can do like `Model::orderBy('created_at, 'desc')->take(5)` to retrieve the 5 latest items. But as I am typing I realize it is probably the same method as `limit(5)`. I was still waking up when I wrote the previous comment.